# ConEmu "Always confirm close" has no effect on new tab created more than 10 secs ago

Tags: bash, python, conemu

I was using ConEmu as the default command line tool in Windows. I had a task set up to start a new tab at a specific start-up directory and execute a python program.

`>* -cur_console:d:c:\to\startup\directory python myapplication.py`

When the application exit, the tab is closed so that all the console print history is lost.

I toggled Settings->Integration->Default term->"Comfirm close" to Always. However the confirmation only occur when closing tab within 10 seconds.

> ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1

If more than 10s, the application will exit directly. How can I make it always confirm on exit? Or even better, can I make the tab not exiting when the application is exited? Like in a normal tab, after a python application is exited, the tab will still be there.

Comment: Obviously, options on the "Default terminal" page have effect only in tabs started via [Default terminal](https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html). See: [-new_console](http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html)